# How does RSpec work with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I am new to `Rails Testing`.

Can anybody suggest a good reference link or some help to explain how I can start RSpec testing for my new project in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails one of the best feature is *TDD* & *BDD* . You can do rails testing using RSpac:

1 -  **Rspecs basics** : http://rspec.info/

2 - **Rspec installation:**   https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails with good examples

3 - **Rspecs installation and how to use:**  http://jonathanhui.com/ruby-rails-3-testing-rspec-2

Comment: Thanks for the `up-votes` , well, If you need more help..don't hasitate!!

Comment: Ruby - that is a *great* user name!

Answer (score 0):

You may find this railscast pretty insightful as well :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec